# Win10 insists Bluetooth is off, cannot turn on

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I'm working on transplanting a PC to a new case. Everything's working so far except the Bluetooth. It's using an Intel 3168 adapter. I updated to the latest Intel drivers.

Win10 insists that Bluetooth is off. Device Manager does not show any Bluetooth adapters at all. BIOS says the Bluetooth radio is on. Intel's "driver information" page says my BT is up to date and running the latest drivers.

It reads

```
Intel® Wireless Bluetooth® for Windows® 10
Latest version: 20.100.6.3
Installed Version: 20.100.6.3

Device Id        USB\VID_8087&PID_0AA7&REV_0001
```

What kind of Windows black magic do I need to perform in order to get this working? It worked when the guts were in the original case, but now... nada.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem with an WiFi adapter. I fixed it like this :

- Open **Device manager**. Select the Bluetooth adapter, disable it. Close the Device manager. Then again open Device manager, select the Bluetooth adapter and enable it.

  OR
- Unplug the Bluetooth adapter and reinsert it.